# Type Polymorphic Functions using Enums

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a factory method with the following signature:

```js
enum FactoryType {
  CAR = 'CAR',
  BIKE = 'BIKE'
}

type CarParamType = {
  cylinders: number
}

type BikeParamType = {
  gears: number
}

factory<F extends FactoryType>(factoryType: F, params: ParamType<F>) {
  switch (factoryType) {
    case FactoryType.CAR:
      return new CarFactory(params);
    case FactoryType.BIKE:
      return new BikeFactory(params);
    default:
       throw new Error('unrecognized factory');
  }

}
```

Where `BikeFactory` and `CarFactory` would have constructors that took in their respective param types.

Is there a way for me to do this in Typescript?  That is, using an Enum, determine the actual type of the `ParamType` is such that I don't get compile errors within the factory method when I try to pass the `params` into their respective constructors?

I thought `ParamType` could look something like this:

```js
type ParamType<T> = T extends FactoryType.CAR ? CarParamType
  : T extends FactoryType.BIKE ? BikeParamType : never;
```

But I don't think there's enough "hints" to give the compiler what it needs.

Comment: @jcalz my apologies, will do!!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w6xxYm) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz It does!! Only after I upgraded typescript, I was apparently running an older version and your answer works for 4.6.x and higher. I'll have to go back and try some of my other solutions using an upgraded typescript compiler as well to see if any of them worked too! Thank you very much, add that answer and I'll gladly mark it as the approved one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only supported way to get the [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) to work with `switch`/`case` statements if for `factoryType` and `params` to be part of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) where `factoryType` is the *discriminant* property.  That requires that they be packaged in a single object, and even though it doesn't look like it, they are.  You can think of `factory()` as having a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) whose type is a discriminated union of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions):

```
function factory(
  ...args:
    [FactoryType.CAR, CarParamType] |
    [FactoryType.BIKE, BikeParamType]
) {
  switch (args[0]) {
    case FactoryType.CAR:
      return new CarFactory(args[1]); // okay
    case FactoryType.BIKE:
      return new BikeFactory(args[1]); // okay
  }
}
```

That works, but you've lost your `factoryType` and `params` names.  Luckily, TypeScript also supports [*destructured* discriminated unions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions), where you destructure into separate variables but the compiler keeps track of the relationship between those variables as if they were properties of the original discriminated union.  That brings us to:

```
function factory(
  ...[factoryType, params]:
    [FactoryType.CAR, CarParamType] |
    [FactoryType.BIKE, BikeParamType]
) {
  switch (factoryType) {
    case FactoryType.CAR:
      return new CarFactory(params); // okay
    case FactoryType.BIKE:
      return new BikeFactory(params); // okay
  }   
}
```

The code compiles to the slightly weird `function factory(...[factoryType, params]) {...}` instead of `function factory(factoryType, params) {...}`, but it acts the same.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.9.5#code/KYOwrgtgBAYghgYwC4HsBOBPAKhgDsKAbwFgAoKKAYQEEAlKAXigHIbbmAaMigIQEkA0gFFGLfsOZkAvmTJI8BSnDQAFZXAg58okuSgIMAGwCWIACbA0AZwBcUcBABGl6bNLztPYwGtgatBpaBEy6FADmwMq29pDOaK6kZAiGcFZWVMrwyOgYRNz6KCBWSGhg2WgAFAh2SqrqmgoAlERQMqRtyanpXr5ZqJh5egiFxaXlFY52PX71Qc2ErQluAGZgIMjGhVDLiP0YAAwV+QB0p8phtvkUANp9OUHHbBwZdQEN+AC6UAA+V1C3u3uCmO4iEz2m-kCCg+ZHm+SsAHdjEgEAALKAVc5Wa77D5wvQUBCpAh3TAPNg2P4UNDAJBgNAgezABEvUkYTFoC7XACMeIA3H8iVYSYCycDQZSCRQoDS6QymSzpmyOVzeY0BXo2m0yKt1khNoyduV2SdTtcjXsgs9cPUrB9JdL-mzyXRnrVIe9gF9flKAcaHqDwT4Zm8gjDSPiKIjkWiMRagfhI9KhSL-cCKVSZbT6YyQMzWaL2Ta3lZ1YLibBCwHBEIHY6s3Lc-mlYWKsWNKWNRRte0gA)